# Why every $p$-group of infinite order is not simple?

Tags: gr.group-theory, p-groups

Why every $p$-group of infinite order is not simple?

Answer (score 12):

The statement is not true: [Tarski monsters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group) of prime exponent $p\gg 10^{70}$ are simple $p$-groups.

Comment: It seems to be not clear what the statement even *is*.  What is a "$p$-group of infinity order"?  (It's not clear to me that a very large finite group is meant to qualify.)  A pro-finite group?  Which definition of simplicity?  (For that matter, is "every … is not simple" meant as a universally quantified statement, or as the *negation* of a universally quantified statement?)

Comment: A $p$-group by definition is a group where every element is of order $p^n$ for some $n$. In the case of finite groups it coincides with the standard definition. And in the case of infinite groups it is the definition.

Comment: But we could with equal validity interpret the statement as "not every  $p$-group of infinite order is simple", which is true. That's the same as the standard interpretation of "all that glitters is not gold".

Comment: @DerekHolt: Which statement did you interpret? The OP?

Comment: @MarkSapir, thanks; obviously I am not a group theorist.  I guess the definition of simplicity is the same as for finite groups (no proper, non-trivial normal subgroups); or are some exceptions allowed (say, maybe finite normal subgroups are still allowed in an infinite simple group)?  I ask because my background is in algebraic groups, where one often ignores finite normal subgroups (so that sometimes special linear groups are called simple as algebraic groups even though their groups of rational points over finite fields are not simple).

Comment: @MarkSapir  I was interpreting the OP's statement "every $p$-group of infinite order is not simple". That could mean either no infinite $p$-group is simple (which is false) or not every infinite $p$-group is simple, which is true.

Comment: @LSpice The standard definition is that a group $G$ is simple if $|G|>1$ and $G$ has no normal subgroups other than $G$ and $\{ 1 \}$ (or, equivalently, if $G$ has exactly two normal subgroups). But if $G$ is a topological group, such as a pro $p$-group, then it is not unusual for "simple" to be used to mean no proper nontrivial closed normal subgroups.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Indeed, I did not notice the second interpretation. This is what happens when English is not the first language.

Comment: @LSpice: Tarski monsters from the link I gave do not have any non-trivial normal subgroups. "Non-trivial" means "non-identity and not the whole group".

Comment: @LSpice: Of course these groups are very far from being algebraic. In fact, for linear groups (that is groups which can be faithfully represented by matrices over a field) your statement is true, I believe.

Comment: Schur's and Kegel's theorems from groupsrings.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/lytkina-mazurov.pdf show that, indeed, there are no infinite simple linear $p$-groups (in char=0).

Comment: @MarkSapir I didn't intend to make any statement, only ask about a definition; and I didn't mean to argue about the Tarski monsters (I only misunderstood and thought they were finite).  Algebraic-group theorists very often call special linear groups simple (because they only have finite normal subgroups), and finite-group theorists never do (because they *do* have non-trivial normal subgroups, with some small exceptions), and I just wanted to know which definition was in force for infinite groups.

Comment: @LSpice: I do not understand your last comment. The statement in your question is not true for arbitrary groups and is true for linear groups at least in char 0. Probably for any characteristic.

Comment: @MarkSapir, I'm really confused; I don't know what statement of mine you are saying is not true, and the only questions I asked were about the definitions of "$p$-group" and of "simple" in the infinite setting.  Just in case this is the source of the confusion, I am not the one who posted the [original question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/94861) (that's user [rose](https://mathoverflow.net/users/23133/rose)).

Comment: @LSpice: Sorry! I assumed that you are the author of the question. I hope your questions are answered now.

Comment: I guess the "rose" wilted 6 years ago.

Comment: Assuming that Tarski monster means "non-abelian and generated by any two non-commuting elements" (so that every proper subgroup is cyclic), it's clear that every Tarski monster of prime exponent $p$ is simple. The "$p>10^{75}$" condition is here to ensure the existence of such groups. In general if a Tarski monster $G$ has finite exponent $n$, it's still very close from simple: its center $Z$ is finite cyclic of order a proper divisor of $n$, and contains every proper normal subgroup of $G$ (so $G/Z$ is a simple Tarski monster of exponent dividing $n$).